# Can these two functions be combined into one?

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting

I've just finished working on a mini task that's described in the comment block in the code below, but I've been trying to make the code better by combining `getRareDigits` and `displayRareDigits` into one function. No matter what I do, the logic always ends up breaking. Can anyone explain to me if it's possible for these two functions to even be combined? Thanks ^_^

```
/*
    Written by: Stephanie Yumiko

* This program will ask the user
for a series of integers, defined by
the user.

* The program will display back to the
user the number of rare digits, digits
that only occur once in a single integer,
but not the rest. 

* The program will then sort the integers
based on the number of occurrences of
rare digits it contains, from greatest
to least.
*/

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

bool num_contains(int, int);
void showRareDigits(int*, int);
void sortRareDigits(int*, int* , int);

bool num_contains(int digit, int n) {
    while (n) {
        if (digit == n % 10) return true;
        n /= 10;
    }
    return false;
}

void getRareDigits(int *arr, int *ordered, int len) {
    for (int index = 0; index < len; ++index) {
        int n = arr[index];
        if (n < 0)
            n *= -1;
        int d = 0;
        while (n) {
            d = n % 10;
            int i;      // keep track of loop counter outside the loop
            int stop = 0; // to break out loop
            for (i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
                if (i != index && num_contains(d, arr[i]))
                    stop = 1;
            }
            // only increment the array if the loop exited before
            // completing (implying the goto would have happened)
            if (!stop) {
                ++ordered[index];
            }
            // always execute 
            n /= 10;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i<len; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j<len - i - 1; j++) {
            if (ordered[j]<ordered[j + 1]) {
                int temp = ordered[j];
                ordered[j] = ordered[j + 1];
                ordered[j + 1] = temp;

                int temp2 = arr[j];
                arr[j] = arr[j + 1];
                arr[j + 1] = temp2;
            }
        }
    }

    cout << "\nArray after sort:\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        cout << arr[i] << endl;
    }
}

void showRareDigits(int* iAry, int size) {
    const int size2 = 10;
    int* tmpAry = new int[size];
    int totalCount[size2] = { 0 };
    int currentCount[size2] = { 0 };
    int totalUncommon = 0;
    int i, j;
    int* ordered;
    ordered = new int[size];

    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        ordered[i] = 0;
        tmpAry[i] = iAry[i];
        if (tmpAry[i] < 0)
            tmpAry[i] *= -1;

        for (j = 0; j < size2; j++)
            currentCount[j] = 0;

        if (tmpAry[i] == 0) {
            currentCount[0] = 1;
        }

        while (tmpAry[i] / 10 != 0 || tmpAry[i] % 10 != 0){
            currentCount[tmpAry[i] % 10] = 1;
            tmpAry[i] /= 10;
        }

        for (j = 0; j < size2; j++) {
            totalCount[j] += currentCount[j];
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < size2; i++) {
        if (totalCount[i] == 1) {
            totalUncommon++;
        }
    }

    cout << "\nTotal rare digits: " << totalUncommon << endl
        << "\nThe rare digits:\n";
    if (totalUncommon == 0) {
        cout << "\nNo rare digits found.";
    }
    else {
        for (i = 0; i < size2; i++) {
            if (totalCount[i] == 1) {
                cout << i << endl;
            }
        }
    }

    getRareDigits(iAry, ordered, size);

    delete[] tmpAry;
    delete[] ordered;

    return;
}


int main() {    
    int size;
    int* arr;

    cout << "Enter # of integers: ";
    cin >> size;
    arr = new int[size];

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        cout << "Enter the value for #" << i << " : ";
        cin >> arr[i];
    }

    cout << "Array before sorting:\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        cout << arr[i] << endl;
    }

    showRareDigits(arr, size);  

    delete[] arr;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: *Can anyone explain to me if it's possible for these two functions to even be combined?* It's not too hard to combine two functions. My suggestion will be not to even attempt that. It's better to have smaller and well defined functions than one large function.

Comment: I suggest writing small functions that do stuff that can be used more than once. So, if a function is to calculate something based on some inputs, it should return the results of that calculation to the caller, not print them to the screen and return nothing. Build your code out of small functions like that and bring them together into an "application".

Comment: Actual improvements would be to use `std::vector` and to separate the tasks *more*, not less. Unless you can describe what each single function does is one sentence without using the words "and" or "or", it's probably too complex.

Answer (score 1):

Your two functions are big and clunky as is. Sometimes that's difficult to avoid, but combining them into one is not a good idea.

Instead try to figure out which logic is common to them and put that into individual functions that you can use from the get… and display… functions.

Also you should have a look at *continue* and *break* to break out of loops. Despite popular belief *goto* is a viable option to break out of multiple loop levels and can be used to simplify your code and make it shorter and easier to comprehend.

Comment: My professor said to not use break, continue, or goto unless you're inside a `switch` statement, not sure why, but I followed his instructions. Thank you I will keep that in mind. :)

Comment: He might just want you to focus on certain aspects of the language. That he told you not to do something doesn't necessarily mean it's wrong. It's just not what you're supposed to practice.

Answer (score 1):

There is some commonality and some big differences between those two functions. Which means that making one function to do both things is definitely not the right thing to do.

Breaking out the COMMON functionality, and leave the overall logic in the functions as is. For example, writing a function that identify the rare digits in an integer would help your code, because you need that information in two different places, and you have loops to calculate that in both places.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really an answer, because you shouldn't combine those functions.
Instead, you should factor the program differently.

This is my suggestion:

There are *three* places where you break a number down into separate digits, so this is clearly a job for a separate function.
It's easier to do this with strings, as we're not interested in what the digits *are*, only whether they're unique.

```
// Return the number of "rare" digits in 'i'; digits which occur only once.
int rare_digits(int i)
{
    std::map<char, int> frequency;
    std::string s = std::to_string(i);
    // Count the characters
    for (auto c : s)
    {
        frequency[c]++;
    }
    // Count how many were unique
    int rare = 0;
    for (auto f: frequency)
    {
        if (f.second == 1)
        {
            rare++;
        }
    }
    return rare;
}
```

and if we store the data in a structure, we can carry the number of rare digits along with the number itself.
This way, we only need to compute the number once.

```
struct Rarity
{
    Rarity(int n, int r)
        : number(n),
          rarity(r) {}
    int number;
    int rarity;
};
```

For sorting, a custom comparison operator is useful:

```
bool operator< (const Rarity& lhs, const Rarity& rhs)
{
    return lhs.rarity > rhs.rarity;
}
```

Everything else we need is provided by the standard library:

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<Rarity> numbers;
    int input = 0;
    while (std::cin >> input)
    {
        int rarity = rare_digits(input);
        // Filter out the "non-rare" numbers early, since they're not interesting
        if (rarity > 0)
        {
            numbers.emplace_back(input, rarity);
        }
    }

    std::sort(numbers.begin(), numbers.end());
    std::cout << numbers.size() << " numbers contained rare digits." << std::endl;
    std::cout << "These numbers were:" << std::endl;
    for (const auto& r: numbers)
    {
        std::cout << r.number << " (" << r.rarity << " rare digits)" << std::endl;
    }
}
```